# Replace M for N in words finished on M, but the M it self

Tags: php, regex, replace

**Problem:** I need to replace 'm' for 'n' in all words finished on 'm', but not the 'm' it self.

**Example text:** Bombom has an m.

**Expected return:** Bombon has an m.

**Current PHP code:** `$txt = preg_replace('/(m)(?=\\s|$)/i', 'n', $txt);`

**But it returns:** Bombon has an n.

---

**Bonus one:** I want "Word" to be `[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]`, so, `3m` should not be replaced for `3n`.

**Bonus two** (for another similar problem)**:** Tell me how to replace `Use Q for Iraq and Qatar` for `Use Q for Irak and katar` (replace all occurences except when alone).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a class assignment.

Comment: Nope, I just to need create a function similar to [SOUNDEX](http://php.net/manual/es/function.soundex.php) for a 
foreign language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are looking for a `m` which appears only at the end of a word, i.e it should be followed by a word boundary but preceded by a letter. You can use `negative lookbehind` like this.

**Regex**: `/(?<=[A-Za-z])m\b/`

**Explanation**:

`m\b` matches the `m` followed by a word boundary. So `Bombom` and `m` should match. But we need only `Bombom`. So use `negative lookbehind`.

`(?<=[A-Za-z])` looks for a letter before matched `m`.

And then replace it with `n`.

**It doesn't matches `3m` since `m` is preceded by a digit.**

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tP3hB5/2)**</kbd>

Comment: Good!! Thanks for the helpfull response.

Comment: @KennyLajara: Didn't understood your **Bonus two** part. Care to elaborate ?

Comment: Hey, very good!! tryed and worked! So, this is not the solition for the "Bonus two", but know I know how to solve it too. Thanks.

Comment: @KennyLajara: I have modified my answer to reject `3m`. Now it only matches `m` followed by word boundary and preceded by a letter.

Comment: Good, now is the simplest solution. I just added replaced `[a-zA-Z]` for `[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]` and it also allow another letters I need.

Comment: @KennyLajara: I hope that helped.

Comment: I upvoted, but even when I read stackoverflow a lot, it is my first post, so, I when I get enought points it should appear (I think I have only 2 more).

Answer (score 0):

No regex but this will do it..

```
function replaceLastLetter($search, $replace, $subject){
    $words = explode(" ", $subject);
    for($i=0; $i<count($words); $i++){
        $last = substr($words[$i], -1);
        if($last == $search && strlen($words[$i])>1){
            $words[$i] = substr($words[$i], 0, strlen($words[$i])-1).$replace;
        }
    }
    return implode(" ", $words);
}
```

https://3v4l.org/lJ4WN

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I had not occurred. Although anyway I'm doing where are a lot of regular expressions, so if I do not find that the solution that way, your way would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `[^\w]` for matching non-letters/digits, and include them again in your replacement string:

```
$input = "Bombom has an m, not 3m.";
$output = preg_replace("/([a-zÀ-ÿ])m($|[^\w])/i", "$1n$2", $input);
echo $output . "<br>";
```

Output:

> Bombon has an m, not 3m.

The regex will grab the preceding letter, which must be a letter (`a-zÀ-ÿ`), as group 1, and the following a non-letter/digit `[^\w]` (or end of string `$`) as group 2, and restore these with `$1` and `$2` respectively in the replacement string.

For the case with Q, you could use this:

```
$input = "Use Q for Iraq and Qatar";
$output = preg_replace("/(?:([a-zÀ-ÿ])q($|[^\w])|(^|[^\w])q($|[a-zÀ-ÿ]))/i",
                       "$1$3k$2$4", $input);
echo $output . "<br>";
```

Output:

> Use Q for Irak and katar

Here the principle is extended with an OR operation (`|`). As there are now 4 capturing groups, all four need to be restored in the replacement string, even though only two of them will be actualised. The other two will be the empty string, so it does not destroy the result if they are also there.

The `i` option at the end of the regex makes sure both `q` and `Q` are matched (case-insensitive).

Comment: Fixed error concerning `\w`. Need to use `a-zÀ-ÿ` after all.